# Form validation popup window message works only if change is made in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ionic-framework

I have a form which need to show validation error popup window message if clicked submit.
Here is my form.

```
 <form ng-submit="register(user)">
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="user.first" >
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="user.last">
  </label>
</div>
<button class="button button-positive">
  button-positive
</button>
</form>
```

Here is the validation controller file

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers',[])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$ionicPopup,Friends) {


    $scope.register=function(user){
      if(!user.first){ $ionicPopup.alert({
                       title: 'First Name Required!',
                       template:'Firstname'
                       });
      }else{
            if(!user.last){
                           $ionicPopup.alert({
                           title: 'Last Name Required!',
                           template:'Lastname'
                           });
              }else {


                        Friends.setall(user).then(function(msg){
                             console.log("From server"+msg.data);

                          });
              }

        }
    }

})
```

Validation works normally when  start making changes. But it doesn't show any error messages If clicked submit without entering anything.How can i achieve this? also i want to 
show  loading screen for the server request and it is dissmissed when the server request is complete.I am using ionicframework,and i know `ionic.loading` is used for this but How can i properly used this in my code?.Please help.

Comment: Why not let Angular do the validation directly on the form rather than having the logic in your controller and a popup?  If its a required field than put the HTML5 attribute on it `required`.  Else you can check to see if the form is "`$dirty`" https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: I worked on mobile apps and i think popup message is better for error messages rather than text because user can easily notify the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the validation part of your question, I would just check for `user` along with `user.firstname`:

```
if(!user || !user.first){ $ionicPopup.alert({
  title: 'First Name Required!',
  template:'Firstname'
});
```

and you can use `$ionicLoading`, after injecting it into the controller, like this:

```
else {
  $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Loading...' });
  Friends.setall(user).then(function(msg){
    console.log("From server"+msg.data);
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you give an answer for this? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831459/pushnotifcation-in-phongap-android-multiple-registrion-ids-of-the-same-device)