# Angularjs form validation works only if changes made in the form fields

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, validation, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement form validation using angularjs.Validation  works correctly when user start to make changes in the form fields.But it doesn't show any error messages If clicked submit without entering anything.Here is the code

```
<form name="myform" ng-submit="register(user)" >
        <div class="list ">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">Name</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="John Watson" ng-model="user.name" name="user_name" required>
                <span style="color:red;" ng-show="myform.user_name.$dirty&&myform.user_name.$error.required">Name required</span>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">Mobile Number</span>
                <input type="tel" ng-minlength="10"  maxlength="10" ng-model="user.mobileno"  placeholder="77777777" name="user_mobileno"  required>
                <span style="color:red;" ng-show="myform.user_mobileno.$dirty&&myform.user_mobileno.$error.minlength">Please provide a valid mobileNo</span>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">Service Provider</span><br><br>
                <select class="clearfix" style="width:100%; height:30px;" ng-model="user.svp_name" name="user_svp_name" required>
                    <option value="">Select one </option>
                    <option value="xxxx">xxxx</option>
                    <option value="xxxx">xxx</option>

                </select><br><br>
                <span style="color:red;" ng-show="myform.user_svp_name.$dirty&&myform.user_svp_name.$error.required">Select your service provider</span>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">Email Id</span>
                <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="john@example.com" name="user_email" required>
                <span style="color:red;" ng-show="myform.user_email.$dirty&&myform.user_email.$error.email">Please Provide a valid emailId</span>
            </label>

        </div>
        <div style="padding:0 10px;">
            <input type="submit"   class="button button-balanced button-block buttonradius" value="Register" />
        </div><br /><br />
        </form>
```

I've already refered these questions ([AngularJS validation on submit only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855082/angularjs-validation-on-submit-only?rq=1)),
([Form validation popup window message works only if change is made in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749371/form-validation-popup-window-message-works-only-if-change-is-made-in-angularjs))
,but didnt help me

**UPDATE**
Finally i found a solution but its not working as i expected.These are the changes

```
<span style="color:red;" ng-show="submitted&&myform.user_name.$error.required">Name required</span>
<input type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true" class="button button-balanced button-block buttonradius" value="Register" />
```

but only work in `name` and `serviceprovider` fields(shows the error messages if clicked submit without entering anything),not other two fields(mobileno,email).

Comment: Can you reproduce the same in Chrome or other browser?

Comment: I've tested in phone

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="color:red;" ng-show="myform.user_name.$dirty&&myform.user_name.$error.required">Name required</span>
```

`myform.user_name.$dirty` is why it's only showing if the field was edited before submitting form. `$dirty` isn't set until the form field is changed.

What I usually do is put a `failed` boolean on my scope and after submit if the form is invalid I set `$scope.failed = true;`. So if you went that route, you would change your ng-shows to:

```
<span style="color:red;" ng-show="failed && myform.user_name.$error.required">Name required</span>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.register = function(user) {
  if ($scope.myForm.$invalid) {
    // Form is invalid
    $scope.failed = true;
    return;
  }
  delete $scope.failed;


  // Other submission logic
};
```

Comment: How can I check  the form is invalid

Comment: @Root oops! I updated my answer. You could also put the myForm.$invalid in the ng-show, but this way it's only going to show the error message after somebody tried to submit your form instead of right away when the form loads.

Comment: This is i tried `failed&&myform.user_name.$error.required&&myform.user_name.$invalid` but didnt work

Comment: @Root Keep it simple. Do you really need all those AND's (&&). The way it's written, _all three_ conditions _must_ be true to display the error message. Are you sure that's right?